# Error: "No instances for (x)..."

Tags: haskell, types, instances

Exercise 14.16-17 in Thompson asks me to add the operations of multiplication and (integer) division to the type Expr, which represents a simple language for arithmetic, then define the functions *show* and *eval* (evaluates an expression of type Expr) for Expr.

My solution works for each arithmetic operation except division:

```
data Expr = L Int
          | Expr :+ Expr
          | Expr :- Expr
          | Expr :* Expr
          | Expr :/ Expr

instance Num Expr where
 (L x) + (L y) = L (x + y)
 (L x) - (L y) = L (x - y)
 (L x) * (L y) = L (x * y)

instance Eq Expr where
 (L x) == (L y) = x == y

instance Show Expr where
 show (L n) = show n
 show (e1 :+ e2) = "(" ++ show e1 ++ " + " ++ show e2 ++ ")"
 show (e1 :- e2) = "(" ++ show e1 ++ " - " ++ show e2 ++ ")"
 show (e1 :* e2) = "(" ++ show e1 ++ " * " ++ show e2 ++ ")"
 show (e1 :/ e2) = "(" ++ show e1 ++ " / " ++ show e2 ++ ")"

eval :: Expr -> Expr
eval (L n) = L n
eval (e1 :+ e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (e1 :- e2) = eval e1 - eval e2
eval (e1 :* e2) = eval e1 * eval e2
```

E.g.,

```
*Main> (L 6 :+ L 7) :- L 4
  ((6 + 7) - 4)
*Main> it :* L 9
  (((6 + 7) - 4) * 9)
*Main> eval it
  81
  it :: Expr
```

However, I am running into problems when I try to implement division. I don't understand the error message I receive when I try to compile the following:

```
instance Integral Expr where
 (L x) `div` (L y) = L (x `div` y)

eval (e1 :/ e2) = eval e1 `div` eval e2
```

This is the error:

```
Chapter 14.15-27.hs:19:9:

No instances for (Enum Expr, Real Expr)
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
               at Chapter 14.15-27.hs:19:9-21
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Enum Expr, Real Expr)
In the instance declaration for `Integral Expr'
```

In the first place, I have no idea why defining `div` for the data type Expr requires me to define an instance of `Enum Expr` or `Real Expr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's the way the `Integral` typeclass is defined. For information, you can e.g. just type `:i Integral` into *GHCi*.

You'll get

```
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where ...
```

which means any type `a` that should be `Integral` has to be `Real` and `Enum` first. C'est la vie.

---

Note that maybe you've got your types messed up quite a bit. Take a look at

```
instance Num Expr where
 (L x) + (L y) = L (x + y)
 (L x) - (L y) = L (x - y)
 (L x) * (L y) = L (x * y)
```

This *just allows you to add `Expr`essions if they wrap plain numbers*. I'm pretty sure you don't want that.
You want to add *arbitrary expressions* and you already have a syntax for this. It's just

```
instance Num Expr where
  (+) = (:+)
  (-) = (:-)
  -- ...
```

This allows you to write `(L 1) + (L 2)` with perfectly normal syntax. Likewise, `eval` should not just reduce expressions but yield a number, and therefore have the type `eval :: Expr -> Integer`. Division is simple for that matter

```
eval (a :/ b) = (eval a) `div` (eval b)
```

which is defined since you just divide *numbers*.

Comment: So the function 'div' doesn't require overloading certain functions for Real or Enum, but being an instance of Integral requires being an instance of Real and Enum? Okay, thanks.

Comment: No, `div` is just available as the instance method of class `Integral` and therefore requires your type to be `Real` and `Enum` too. But read my edited answer ... you probably don't want that.

Comment: Well, I know that I could have defined an operator c as (c) = (:c) in an instance declaration for Num Expr, and that 'eval' is supposed to return an Int; but that exercise was more boring than having eval return a value of type Expr. If that isn't what you mean, though, then perhaps I 'really do' have my types messed up.

Comment: I don't quite get that you mean with your operator c, but just define `eval :: Expr -> Int` and I'm pretty sure it'll work ;)

Comment: I guess I'm dense, I just realized what you meant in your edit, although I don't understand why I have my types 'messed up.' Thanks for your help!